# excel sumproduct formula calculating time

Tags: excel, dashboard

hello dear forum members and admins,

i created a dashboard to calculate customer numbers based on raw data prepared on day and time set.

there is no problem here I can calculate. but I also want to calculate the monthly average customer numbers based on the time set. for this purpose, I created a data table in a daily_pax_sheet. for e.g in January between 10:00 - 10:30 CUSTOMERS E totally number is 35 and this 35 amount occurred in 8 days, then it calculates 4 amounts. in daily_pax_details sheet row 107 formula firstly calculate sum of the data then it divides the day number (for e.g this amount occurs in 8 days) but in some cases, raw data include more than 20k line and it's calculating and waiting too much. is there any other way to do it in a quick way ? how can I change this formula to make calculation quick ?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y-2Ke2ssskzSM-wYszU54CIEraPbEX4X/edit#gid=459027650

**UPDATE**: thanks for the idea and solution from members
I also realized another solution and I think it will help other people in the future. we can get the data to the pivot table with counting the unique values with changing field settings. To do it you should get the data pivot table with selecting "add this data to the data model". then changing value field settings with the "Distinct value". hope it will help another pppl.

Comment: Welcome to SO. * it's calculating and waiting too much* But your formula works. Latency is due, probably, to calculate so many data. Consider working on manual mode on workbook so it does not recalculate all the time.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/current-mode-of-calculation

Comment: Whole column references will slow things down. You might be better off by using a **Table** with structured references (which will auto-adjust depending on your data size).  Also, it might be faster to do this in VBA or Power Query, but hard to know without realistic data (and a clear explanation of your process) to work with.

Comment: thank you so much for your comments how can I attach a file ? 
 I tried many things to do that in an quick way changed ranges with the table structured references and also sumproduct formula changed with sum but still its calculating more than 30 minutes I had to escape calculation I don't know maybe it would take 2 hours :( 
 waiting for your help @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Comment: You can share the file with google Drive and editing your original question and adding the link Anyways, in the link I provided teach how to change to calculation manual

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hello all, thank you again for your i added the link of the excel file. in the daily_pax_details sheet I added a formula and created table starting from 107th row. this formula and table slowing down the calculation a lot around 40mins. how should I solve this issue ? thanks again 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTJQJdMpFWrfFxy4-7_bs2Uv3YIw6GickQTqMPo-0xrfPS2pLVXJnDz54-Z7Z1w_Q/pubhtml

Comment: The way you've shared this is not useful because the download is not possible. Nobody can check why it ttakes 40 minutes. Agai, ¿did you try Manual?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thank you for your response , i have made a mistake could you please try to download this link ?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y-2Ke2ssskzSM-wYszU54CIEraPbEX4X/edit#gid=459027650

Answer (score 0):

Your SUMIFS formulas use whole columns as criteria, so every calculation checks more than 1 million cells. And because you use more than 1 column, then every time you update **anything* in the file, Excel checks more than 4 million cells because of your formulas...

I changed all to use the righ `rawdata` range of cells used, not whole columns. And now it works perfect.

As example, your formula is:

```
=SUMIFS('raw data'!$R:$R;'raw data'!$D:$D;'Daily customer'!C$3;'raw data'!$I:$I;'Daily customer'!$A4)
```

And I changed to:

```
=SUMIFS('raw data'!$R$2:$R$2461;'raw data'!$D$2:$D$2461;'Daily customer'!C$3;'raw data'!$I$2:$I$2461;'Daily customer'!$A4)
```

Because in your sheet `raw data` your data goes from row 2 to 2461, so in every calculation Excel checks only 2460 cells, not 1 million....

Change all your formulas like this and you should notice a better performance indeed.

**UPDATE:** I've uploaded the modified file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11isonBHFJTFFWtZTJg66JHbtyrD0XFGl/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114417674018837700466&rtpof=true&sd=true

It works smoothly for me. No lag or anything. I can change any cell value, move the graph, filter cells and everything is done almost instantly.

Comment: i appreciate your comment and help , i changed also range to the table column for e.g table1[Date] but its still working slowly, I think the biggest slowly effect is the table in daily_pax_details sheet G117:P164 in these cells calculating this formula very very slow. if you can also check this one , I would be glad @Foxfire And Burns And Burns

Comment: @itsmylearningjourney Please, check updated answer. Also, check if maybe any installed add-in in Excel is causing the trouble? The file is perfect for me